# Change file name while copying based on source path

Tags: files, rename

I have a large number of files in directories of the format `*/*/*/*/*.txt` and I would like to copy them into a different place while replacing the forward-slashes in the path with underscores. For example, if a file is located at `A/B/C/D/E.txt`, I'd like to copy it to `dest/` so that its path after copying is `dest/A_B_C_D_E.txt`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use script like this:

```
for i in `find . -type f -name "*.txt"`
do
newfile=$(echo $i|sed -s 's@/@_@g'|cut -c -3)
mv "$i" "dest/$newfile"
done
```

If the number of files if very big you can try with `while` instead of `for`

```
while read i
do 
    newfile=$(echo $i|sed -s 's@/@_@g'|cut -c -3)
    mv "$i" "dest/$newfile"
done < (find . -type f -name "*.txt")
```

P.S. Be warned about the filenames/directories with nonstandard symbols in filenames. For reference check [this question and answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/101265)

Comment: This will break on a bunch of filenames.

Comment: @jordanm, can you please clarify?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Anything with spaces, for example, but also files with globbing patterns. See e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697

Comment: @Kusalananda, I agree with most of the things. But let give to OP the opportunity to check if he have such odd filenames/directories :)

Comment: @RomeoNinov Note that an answer is never an answer to a single user and their specific setup. An answer may be read years from now and applied to a setup where files may well have spaces and strange characters in their filenames.

Comment: I noticed that this includes the leading `./` in the path, so this results in filenames starting with `._`, which isn't ideal

Comment: I don't have any odd filenames, so this works for me. However I am hesitant to mark it as an answer because it isn't completely generic

Comment: I was able to fix the leading `._` problem by adding to the `newfile` line:
    `newfile=$(echo $i|sed -s 's@/@_@g'|cut -c -3)`

Comment: @DavidScott, will add it in to the answer